# RFQuiltLayout and UICollectionView margin

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am trying to use RFQuiltLayout in my Collection View and I keep running into an size/margin issue. It seems appears fine using the 4s and 5s simulator but when I test it on the 6 or 6plus, the blocks get pushed over to the left side of the screen and leave a large margin on the right.

Not sure what's going on here.

[image of problem](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mzs4ln0g4omstcr/Screen%20Shot%202015-07-28%20at%209.00.33%20PM.png?dl=0)

[storyboard](https://www.dropbox.com/s/864yap9atv2dqna/Screen%20Shot%202015-07-28%20at%209.17.07%20PM.png?dl=0)

Here is the code for the collection view controller

**.h**

```
#import "RFQuiltLayout.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, RFQuiltLayoutDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *greekLetters;
```

**.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CollectionViewCell.h"
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    RFQuiltLayout* layout = (id)[self.collectionView collectionViewLayout];
    layout.direction = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;
    layout.blockPixels = CGSizeMake(75, 75);
    
    
     self.greekLetters = @[@"Alpha", @"Beta", @"Cappa",@"Delta", @"Epsilon", @"Zeta", @"Eta", @"Theta", @"Iota", @"Kappa", @"Lambda", @"Mu", @"Nu", @"Xi", @"omicron", @"pi",@"rho",@"sigma", @"tau", @"upsilon", @"phi", @"chi",@"psi",@"omega"];
    
    

    
  //  [[self collectionView]setDataSource:self];
   // [[self collectionView]setDelegate:self];
    
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma - mark CollectionView DelegateMethods:


-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return self.greekLetters.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSString *CellIdentifer = @"cell";
    CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifer forIndexPath:indexPath];
    
    cell.cellLabel.text = [self.greekLetters objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    
    return cell;

}


#pragma mark – RFQuiltLayoutDelegate


-(CGSize) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout blockSizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    
    if (indexPath.row %2) {
        return CGSizeMake(2, 3);
        
    }else{
        return CGSizeMake(2, 2);
    }
}

- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetsForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5);
}

@end
```

Not sure what could be causing it.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

just play with  the blockpixels 
for mine these **values** work perfectly

```
layout.blockPixels = CGSizeMake(106.66, 106.66);
```